# Text area cursor

Tags: javascript, html

After I submit my texts to the chat box I made the cursor does not stay inside the text area where I was typing . How can I make it automatically appear so the user need not click again and again . Really need help thanks in advance.

Thanks to all.I was really relieved.

Comment: How about using `textarea.focus()`?

Comment: How about adding some code, showing us what you've tried, and what the current code looks like.

Comment: Should I only write down textarea.focus ? or any thing else.I tried this somehow did not work.

Comment: just add `autofocus` -> `<textarea autofocus></textarea>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can keep focus of  the text area  when clicking particular button

try using below jquery

```
<textarea id="status2" placeholder="Write here..." name="new_entry"></textarea>

$('#btn').click(function(){
$("#status2").focus();
});
```

hope it helps.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: welcome.if the solution works accept as answer.

Comment: I am new in stack overflow. Accepted but not working some how.

Comment: Can I accept multiple solutions ?

Comment: i can't get you exactly what you meant.

Comment: u can't accept multiple solutions. accept any one solution which works fine

Comment: Okay accepted yours. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

Simply focus the text field with [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.focus) method:

```
document.getElementById('text_field').focus();
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. Can you kindly suggest where to add this?
I am a biginer.

Comment: @user3127524 You may add this line inside the `<script></script>` tag right after your text field.

Comment: So kind of you. Got it.